# I'm not sure how to understand "事業者の幹部" in this sentence

Tags: reading-comprehension

> ある海外のカジノ**事業者の幹部**から聞いた言葉です。ＲＧとは、Responsible
>   Gambling、日本語にすれば「責任あるギャンブル」となります。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0807.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_008))

事業者 implies an executive position so I don't understand the role of の幹部?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「事業者{じぎょうしゃ}」 can mean a "business", "company", etc. as well as a "businessman".  Its usage for the first meaning is actually very common in the real Japanese-speaking world.

Thus, 「カジノ事業者の幹部{かんぶ}」 is a perfectly natural and grammatical phrase meaning the "casino company executive(s)".

It seems you probably took the kanji 「者」 too literally.